# Placing a margin around each edge of the UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

When the UICollectionView is populated with items they always go right to the edges of the UICollectionView like so:

```
---------------
|X X X X X X X|
|X X X X X X X|
|X X X X X X X|
|X X X X X X X|
|X X X X X X X|
|X X X X X X X|
---------------
```

I would like to place a margin around each edge like so:

```
---------------
| X X X X X X |
| X X X X X X |
| X X X X X X |
| X X X X X X |
| X X X X X X |
| X X X X X X |
---------------
```

I tried to achieve this by placing the UICollectionView inside its hosting UIView by setting its Frame to simulate a border but it scrolls within the Frame so gets cut off at the top and bottom and the scroller also appears in the bounds of the frame.

I have looked at the API but I cannot see anything obvious to achieve this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In

```
(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
}
```

you can give your cells some margin on the left side.

Or you can create custom cells, which have a margin.

or you can set the property **.sectionInset** of your `CollectionviewFlowLayout`, which should be the easiest way (if you use FlowLayout)

Comment: Don't think cellForItem answers the question, because the question is asking for the collectionViewController's edges, not each cell's edges.

Answer (score 42):

I know this is an old question, but don't forget that UICollectionView inherits from UIScrollView.

```
UICollectionView *collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] init];
collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(x.x, x.x, x.x, x.x);
```

```swift
// Swift 3 for good measure
let collectionView = UICollectionView()
collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: x.x, left: x.x, bottom: x.x, right: x.x)
```

Be aware that both contentInset and sectionInset may change the spacing of cells in your view. For more information on that, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19429189/1445441) post.

Comment: `collectionView.contentInset` is what I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 15):

You can make use of the following function.

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
  {
      return UIEdgeInsetsMake(50, 50,15,50);
  }
```

You will have to play around with the number to figure out how to force the collectionviewCells in a single line.

```
UIEdgeInsetsMake ( CGFloat top,CGFloat left,CGFloat bottom,CGFloat right);
```

**For Swift 3**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 4, 10, 4)
}
```

Comment: This is my favorite solution here - it's much less hacky than giving your cells padding. And the contentInset doesn't always work for me.

Comment: How to make this in swift @Vinayak Kini

Answer (score 9):

You can pretty much control every aspect of the grid with collectionview's protocol. Here's an example:

```
- (UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)collectionViewFlowLayout
{
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [UICollectionViewFlowLayout new];
    flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(180, 255);
    flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 30, 0, 30);
    flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0.0f;
    flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0.0f;
    flowLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical;
    return flowLayout;
}
```

The one you would want to change in your case is the `sectionInsets`

Answer (score 3):

> Swift 2.0

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
self.collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

On Xcode 8, if you're using the interface builder you can set the Section Insets right on the Size Inspector:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4 updated** ([Vinayak Kini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1210553/vinayak-kini) answer) :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
}
```