# How do I achieve spacing between pages in a UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, uipageviewcontroller

UICollection has paging just like a UIPageViewController. With the latter, you have UIPageViewControllerOptionInterPageSpacingKey to easily set the spacing. How is this best achieved with a UICollectionView?

Comment: Never used what you are asking, but as a long shot does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21071043/decrease-space-between-uicollectionviewcells/21074972#21074972

Comment: @DogCoffee Not using flow layout unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

You can probably accomplish explicitly with `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes`, but my approach (that works for collection views and my own subview-containing scroll views) is to tile the cells with no spacing (which makes the layout math simple), but make the cells transparent.

Then within each cell create a more opaque content view whose frame is an insetRect on the cell's bounds.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `collectionView:layout:insetForSectionAtIndex:` method for your UICollectionView. You need to add this code...

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, left, bottom, right);
}
```

it was answered here: [UICollectionView spacing margins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13970950/uicollectionview-spacing-margins) by @michael23